# CreateprocessW change environment variables for python's lib call

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, createprocess

```
wchar_t cmd2[] = L"cmd.exe";

STARTUPINFOW startInf;

memset( &startInf, 0, sizeof startInf );
startInf.cb = sizeof(startInf);

PROCESS_INFORMATION procInf;
memset( &procInf, 0, sizeof procInf );

BOOL b = CreateProcessW( NULL, cmd2, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS| CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, "PYTHONPATH=\"C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\lib;C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\0\0\"", NULL, &startInf, &procInf );


std::cout << "Retour de la commande CreateProcess= " << b << std::endl;
```

I tried the previous code in order to open a console and run some python scripts (have some others environment variables like path which contains python.exe location" but not relevant here).

I can't change the python location and it contains some spaces so i have to introduce some " " on the path.

My issue is the following running this little program, when the console pop-up i tried to run %pythonpath% and i obtained :

> ' "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages"' n'est pas reconnu en tant que co
>   mmande interne
>   ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

I can't use inherited paths since environment called by this used an other version of python and libs that aren't located at the same places.

```
BOOL b = CreateProcessW( NULL, cmd2, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS| CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startInf, &procInf );
```

I want to add multiples values/paths which could contain some spaces on paths.

Does someone have any clue on this one ?

Best regards,

Comment: I don't know what you expect to happen when you try to run `%pythonpath%`; it's just a list of directories. I also don't see why you even need this variable. The `lib` and `lib\site-packages` directories are automatically added to Python's `sys.path`. `PYTHONPATH` is meant for adding user-defined paths to `sys.path`.

Comment: The issue i have is the following : running some scripts outside of a tool used for simulations works perfectly since my paths are already declared as you mentionned. This tool use its own &different python version with its related paths (not located on the same drive).I call python scripts inside the python folder's tool and by the way it calls the wrong version of python and so the wrong librairies folder (matplot lib for instance is not found). To make it works i have to redefine on the child process the path for the right version on python. I don't know if i express my objective clearly...

Comment: If the existing `PYTHONPATH` value has directories for the wrong version (which is why I never use this environment variable anyway), you should just remove it from a copy of the environment -- not strip the environment of all other values and set a new `PYTHONPATH` value that's redundant and pointless. If running "python.exe" finds the wrong version, you need to prepend the target directory to the value of `PATH`, which has nothing to do with `PYTHONPATH`, or simply run `"C:\Program Files\Anaconda\python.exe"` directly via `CreateProcess`. I don't see why you need cmd.exe.

Comment: I did that at the beginning "C:\Program Files\Anaconda\python.exe" D:\XXX\YYY\ZZZ\AAA\BBB\CCC\graph.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\XXX\YYY\ZZZ\AAA\BBB\CCC\graph.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib import pyplot
ImportError: No module named matplotlib   I used cmd instead of calling python to see what's going on... i'm sure that i called the right version of python using the absolute path but the tool searched on the wrong librairies folders and cannot find them, due to, i think, the parent process environment which refer to the wrong python librairies path.